# Как сделать запуск сервера по нажатию кнопки в android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, сервер, сокет

Пытаюсь сделать запуск сервера, но при нажатии кнопки ничего не происходит и не выводится. Подскажите как реализовать запуск сервера при нажатии на кнопку в эмуляторе?

Класс MainActivity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Server server = new Server();
    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.button:
                server.startServer();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Класс Server:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Server {
    public void startServer() {
        int port = 6666;
        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Waiting for a client...");

            Socket socket = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("Got a client");
            System.out.println();

            InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();

            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);

            String line = null;
            while(true) {
                line = in.readUTF();
                System.out.println("The dumb client just sent me this line : " + line);
                System.out.println("I'm sending it back...");
                out.writeUTF(line);
                out.flush();
                System.out.println("Waiting for the next line...");
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch(Exception x) { x.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: у вас код рабочий, вы просто не туда выводите. вместо  `System.out.println("Some string")`,  используйте `Log.d("Server", "Some string");`

Comment: Работа с сетью в UI-потоке?

Comment: Спасибо! Вы правы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Проблемы оказалось целых три:

1. Нужно было использовать `Log.d("Server", "Some string");` для вывода сообщений
2. Забыл добавить `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` в манифест
3. Нельзя выполнять сетевые операции в главном потоке. (Подробнее https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-do-i-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)